# Symfony get session variable inside of entity repository class

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to get a session variable inside of my Symfony2 entity repository class but not quite sure how to accomplish this task.

Basically I am just doing this:

```
$this->get('session')->set('cart_id', $cartId);
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: you would need to declare the repo a service, inject the session service and then *use* the repo as a service (not via doctrine).

Comment: Connecting session with repository layer isn't best idea. Maybe you just can fetch all required data from session on your controller/service and then pass them to repository as method call parameters.

Answer (score 2):

That is not something you want to do. It smells bad design. You should create a service that reads the session variable and sets it to the entity.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do something like that in an EntityRepository. You'd do that in a Controller or Service. 
You can achieve it by declaring the entity repository as a service like the following:

```
parameters:
    entity.sample_entity: "AppBundle:SampleEntity"

services:
    sample_entity_repository:
        class: AppBundle\Repository\SampleEntityRepository
        factory: ["@doctrine", getRepository]
        arguments:
            - %entity.sample_entity%
        calls:
          - [setSession, ["@session"]]
```

You create a setSession method in your Repository class like the following:

```
class SampleRepository extends EntityRepository
{
   private $entity;
   private $session;

   public function __construct(SampleEntity $entity)
   {
      $this->entity = $entity;
   }

   public function setSession(Session $session)
   {
      $this->session = $session;
   }
   .....
}
```

Then in another function set the session variable like $this->session->set('cart_id', $cartId);

Comment: Hi, I have almost the same problem. I am using a Callback in a entity to validate a data against someting present in the session. Should I  do as above, or something else ? Thanks